# Choosing the right Deep Learning Model for Image Segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

How do you choose the appropriate Deep Learning Algorithm if you wanted to do image segmentation with an image datset which consist of hispathology images of almost 10000? I'am new to deep learning and is stuck in the first step which to choose a DeepLearning Algorithm to use. What are the things I should consider in making my choice? For those of you who have experience in image segmentation can I hear your opinion on which is the easiest algorithm to learn and implement?